# Provisioning Profile dropdown list in Visual Studio does not match list of available Provisioning Profiles in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I have created a Distribution Provisioning Profile on the Apple Developer site (in 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles') and have downloaded and installed on my Mac.

I can see it in Xcode, but I cannot see it in Visual Studio on my PC (Properties\iOS Bundle Signing).  In fact, I can't see any Distribution Provisioning Profiles, just Development ones. Despite me choosing the correct Identity in [Visual Studio Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJAmc.png). I have exited Xcode and restarted VS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnect and then re-connect your Mac. This will sync the list provisioning profiles on your PC. (also re-open property window where you select profile)

[image]